# Construct mongodb query with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get a count of users with the email example@email.com via the ajax below:

```
function getCount(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var queryCount = {
    email:'example@email.com'
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: queryCount,
    url: '/countuser',
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function(response) {
    //Check for successful (blank) response
    if(response.msg === '') {

    } else {

    }
});
}
```

and this in users.js:

```
exports.countuser = function(db) {
return function(req, res) {
    db.collection('userlist').find(req.body).count(function(err,count) {
      res.send(count);
    });
  }
};
```

but this isn't working (getting the count of the complete user list, which makes me think that req.body is empty). What would be a correct way of going about this?

Comment: What are you getting for a response? ie console.log(count)

Comment: I'm getting 4 (which is the count of all of my users)

Comment: If I were to put db.collection('userlist').find({email:"example@email.com").count(function(err,count) {
      res.send(count);
    });
I would get 1

Comment: Since this is a get, is the `req.body` empty and `req.params` populated with your data?

Comment: @tymeJV the req.body is in fact empty! I tried req.params as well and its empty. this is why I'm getting a total count

Comment: bah! Pop open your network request tab in dev tools - what is the url the request is being made to? Also, what does your `app.get` route look like?

Comment: this is my app.get route: app.get('/countuser', user.countuser(db));

Comment: as for a response, this is what I'm getting:
([], 
GET /countuser?email=example%40email.com 5 47ms); the [] signifies my req.params which is empty, and the 5 is the count -> total number of users

Comment: Change your route to: `app.get('/countuser/:email'` and then check `req.params`

Comment: hmm doesn't work...i get a 404 response since I'm still calling "url: '/countuser'" from ajax

Comment: @tymeJV he can't have that in the url, it's an email address

Comment: Ahem. So how does your function know about `req` and `res` then?

Comment: well it's strange. I'm using the same function of req and res for other CRUD functions, and they work perfectly

Comment: @NeilLunn I got it working via putting the email as a get variable. is there a reason why this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to pass in just `req.body` but get the param that you posted. But this might be okay as long as you have set up the body parser. There is a better invocation of this but

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

But probably your problem with your function is you are not passing `req` in.

```
exports.countuser = function(db,req,res) {
```

Then you need to pass in not **only** `db` but `req` and `res` as well.

And though you did not post it in your question, your `route` definition needs to change. Arguments to routes are `req` and `res` only as that is what gets passed in:

```
app.get('/countuser',function(req,res) {

    user.countuser(db,req,res);
```

So at the moment you are just getting the **count**, as a number in the response. Which to this point is what you asked for. But that's just a number, it's not JSON. So you need to change a bit.

```
var countResponse = {};

countResponse.count = count;
res.body(countResponse);
```

And you also have an **object** as the data you are passing in. This is not url encoded, use the $.param helper:

```
.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: $.param(queryCount),
    url: '/countuser',
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function(response) {
```

In short there are lot of things wrong here. Take some time and read through the documentation.

Comment: thanks, but the problem right now isn't the countResponse, its that my ajax request's body and params are empty

Comment: @Allen was halfway through writing and triggered a save.

Comment: I'm getting a req is not defined:
app.get('/countuser', user.countuser(db, req ,res));
exports.countuser = function(db, req, res) {...}

Comment: @Allen the call on the route is not right. See the edit.

Comment: changed it to how you have implemented it, but not getting a response from ajax call completely